# UTableView DataSource Setup

Tags: iphone, ios, uitableview

Just wondering why we can't we set the data source to UITableview in the below way rather than returning the data count in one method and returning the data for cell in different method.

Why don't we do something like below?.

```
 UITableView *tableView = [UITableView alloc] init];
 tableView.datasource = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"row1", @"row2", nil];
 tableView.cellIdentifier = @"Identifier";
 tableView.cell = [UITableViewCell alloc] init];

 //delegate methods implemented as properties,
 tableView.rowHeight = 50.0;
 tableView.headerHeight = 100.0
 tableView.headerView = [UIView alloc] init];

 [self.view addSubView:tableView];
```

We can do this right, may not be 100 % correct, we can think of adding some more properties to make the TableView in the same way it works now.

Whey Apple designed the TableView in the way it works now.Helpful if some one could explain the pros and cons of this design with the existing design.

Comment: I did similar things for my own classes sometimes instead of implementing datasource and delegate methods. I want to know why as well.

Answer (score 2):

The problem with this implementation is that you are not getting dequeued cell which will spike your's device memory once you reached up to app's allocated maximum level of memory. On every table row, a new cell is created.

Moreover cellForRowIndexPath method gives you flexibility in customising cell based on row index path.

What if you are rendering two different custom cell, which contains different views, how can you differentiate between them without using cellForRowIndex delegate's method.

Comment: Agree with your first point about dequeue. But for your second point,  I think for different row index path, it can be different customs cells stored in an Array as a porperty to be set in TableView?